# Select BLOB column in php and insert in another table

Tags: php, mysql, blob

How to select and insert a BLOB column in PHP?

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT CONVERT(`order_pdf` USING utf8) AS `order_pdf` ,`order_pdf_size`
                FROM `ord_order` 
                WHERE order_id = %d LIMIT 1", $old_order_id);

if ($data = $this->executeSQL($sql)) {
  if ($data->status != 0){
      $this->view();
    }
}else{
     $error = true;
}

$sql = sprintf(
            "INSERT INTO `ord_order` (order_pdf, order_pdf_size)
                        VALUES ('%s', %d)",          
            $data->order_pdf,
            $data->order_pdf_size);

if ($result = $this->dbh->query($sql)) {
    print_r("test true");
}
```

This code insert the selected BLOB, but the BOLB is not working. In my download function I get an PDF error

Comment: Converting binary data (```CONVERT(`order_pdf` USING utf8)```) damages the file.